# Why I cannot add css and js files from resources/static folder for different pages in spring boot application?

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I try add css and js files from resources/static folder for different pages. I have two pages index.jsp and validate-configuration.jsp. For index.jsp adding css and js files work correct (see picture below).
[image]

But when I go to validate-configuration.jsp css and js files don't download (see picture below).
[image]

And output from console:
[image]
As we can see changes relative path. If early it was like (index.jsp): http://localhost:8090/static/style.css
http://localhost:8090/static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js 
Then it is became like this:
http://localhost:8090/validation/static/style.css
http://localhost:8090/validation/static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js 
Index.jsp html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="static/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Validate-configuration.jsp:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="static/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Folder for static resources is src/main/resources/static/.

Yml configuration for resources: 
`mvc:
        static-path-pattern: /static/**`
Project structure:
    [![enter image description here][4]][4]

I will appreciate for your suggestions.

Comment: add your project structure

Comment: I wrote above that folder for static resources is src/main/resources/static/

Comment: I cannot add picture because don't allow me do it.

Comment: lucumt, I added picture of project structure below.

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring-boot documentation you can read where Spring-boot reads static resources by default.

By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriding the addResourceHandlers method.
If you change the location of your static files to the default one you should be able to reach them by /css/style.css

[Here you can find a simple project structure](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)

Comment: See above, I wrote that css and js files are placed in src/main/resources/static/ folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I cannot add picture of project structure. I do it here:
[image]